# Write an intact data frame to an excel sheet in R

Tags: r, excel, variable-names, writexl

I loaded an sheet form excel in R and want to write a section of it to a new sheet, using the original column names.
Firs attempt:

```
weekdata <-  Data  [ which(Data$week ==weeknr ),]
  
write.xlsx2(x=weekdata, file=Document, 
            sheetName =BLAD , row.names = FALSE, append = TRUE)
```

[weekdata as seen in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIrr4.png)
The data in a colum schow all in the first field as this a list:
c("2020 6", "2020 6", "2020 6", "2020 6", "2020 6",...)
To get the data row by row i have to set row.names=TRUE, but this ads an extra column.

Second attempt was to use the data.frame function:

```
weekdata <- data.frame( Data  [ which(Data$week ==weeknr ),])
```

Now the problem is the column-names change when special symbols are used:(**from "# bl" to "X..bl"**)

Is there a simple solution I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 0):

I have found some solution by adding this line
`names(weekdata)<- names(Data)`